# Use JPA without EJB in a distributed environment

Tags: java, spring, jpa, ejb, distributed

So my boss asked me to look for a way to use JPA in Spring without using EJB in a distributed environment (single DB and multiple sessions reading/writing from/on it). But I have a lot of confusion.
I've used Spring Boot and JPA using entities with `@Entity` annotation in simple projects, and if I understood correctly these are EJBs, right?
So now he told me that he doesn't want to use EJBs, but to find if it's possible, how hard/easy is it and what can be used to correctly manage distributed transactions on the same DB, not having the enterprise beans that, from what I understood, handle this problem easily by themselves.
I know it is confusing, but I don't know where to start or what to look for, and which is the best way to guarantee the ACID properties not using EJBs.

I've read that instead of EJBs, EntityManager and UserTransaction from JTA can be used, to manage transactions manually. Is it good in a distributed environment? What would its behaviour be? How can one guarantee correct update for all sessions?

Answer (score 2):

I do not understand very well your specific beacause you are saying distributed environment but then (single DB and multiple sessions reading/writing from/on it)

**@Entity are not EJBs.**

You can use Spring + JPA instead of EJBs.

The answer ot the part: *"the best way to guarantee the ACID properties not using EJBs."* is: 
Using @EntityManager which handles for you the transactions.
I would use a Controller-Service-Dao approach. Something like this:

```
public abstract class GenericDAO  {
    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="canvasEM") //persistence unit name defined inside persistence.xml 
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }   
}

public interface CanvasDAO {
    void newCanvas();
}

// Java map for a single DB table
@Entity
public class CanvasEntity  {

}

@Repository
public class CanvasDAOImpl extends GenericDAO implements CanvasDAO {    
    @Override
    public void newCanvas()  {
        CanvasEntity e = new CanvasEntity();
        ...
        entityManager.persist(e);   
    }
}

public interface CanvasService {
    CanvasDTO newCanvas(NewCanvasInputDTO in);
}

@Service
public class CanvasServiceImpl implements CanvasService {
    @Autowired
    private CanvasDAO canvasDAO;

    @Override
    public CanvasDTO newCanvas(){   
        return canvasDAO.newCanvas();
    }   
}

@RestController //or @Component
public class MyController{
    @Autowired
    CanvasService canvasService;

    ...
}


persistence.xml
<persistence>
    <persistence-unit name="canvasEM" ....>
</persistence>
```

You can see how I configured JPA and Spring in this example here. Can give you a basic idea: https://github.com/ermalaliraj/connect4

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes I know I've written little specific, the web app we need to develop will work with a single database, but different users at the same time can connect to it and change the same entity on the db, so I guess that what he need to guarantee is that users won't work with unconsistent data (like changing an entity and commiting while the entity has already been changed by someone else). So I'm guessing he's looking for some sort of check on the entity consistency... Is this related to using or not EJBs?

Comment: `EJB` uses `JPA/EntityManager` for db management (transactions), and it warranties for you all the doubt you are pointing out. If you want to get rid of `EJB` you ca use `Spring`, or other framework for the same end.